# error when reading json file using angular resource

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, file, ngresource

I'm trying to use angular ngResource module to fetch data from json file but I get an error 404 on the console - the URL is being concatenated with code following the call to get function.

Here is the error:

localhost prefix/test_data/data.json/function%20(data)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(data);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D

here is the code I'm using:

the json service -

```
angular.module('jsonServices',['ngResource']).factory('JsonService', 
    function ($resource) { 
    return $resource('/test_data/data.json'); 
});
```

the controller using the service:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
.controller('mainController', function ($scope, JsonService) {
        JsonService.get(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
});
```

the app js that starts it all:

```
angular.module('myApp',['myApp.controllers','jsonServices','ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('home',{
        url:'/home',
        template:'some template path goes here',
        controller:'mainController'
    };
});
```

As you can see the "function(data)" is being added to the url as a string. one more thing is when I try to access the json file browsing to its location I can see the content of the json file OK.

Does anyone got this problem before and find a way to solve it? Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing here?

Thanks,

Eran

Comment: Which version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: I've put your code in a plunker, and it seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/aCxGngQyEbNBfxCBtUiG?p=preview

Comment: I know that in plunker it works but here on my dev machine - using node js static server and chrome it gets this error. I thought it related to the fact that I'm not using html5mode(true) - and now when I switched to it it's getting into infinit loop - but that another issue I hope to solve soon.

Comment: I have no idea then. BTW, what happens if you change the call to `JsonService.get({}, function (data) {`?

Comment: I'm getting: error 404 like before but with /test_data/data.json/[object%20Object]

Comment: It seems the first argument is always determined as a `params`, which is strange. Try to set a breakpoint at [angular-resource.js#L470](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/ngResource/resource.js#L470), and see what happens.

Comment: 10x @runTarm - you gave me a hit that helped me a lot. it appears I used a bower package called ng-resource and not angular-resource. switching to angular-resource made it work.

Comment: Glad I could help. And thanks for letting me know there is the `ng-resource` module out there! I could imagine many people have already been confused by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it seems that I used a bower package call ng-resource instead of angular-resource.